# boost::asio::io_service crash in win_mutex lock

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, winsock2

I've been having a problem with boost::asio where timer and/or sockets created using a global io_service instance crash during construction.  The system where the crash occurs is as follows:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop; v 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
- Boost 1.57, dynamically linked, compiled with multithreading as, e.g. boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.dll

I've been able to replicate the issue in the following simplified code:

// file global_io_service.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_GLOBAL_IO_SERVICE_H
#define INCLUDED_GLOBAL_IO_SERVICE_H

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace foo{

extern boost::asio::io_service test_io_service;

class foo_base_io_service{ 

public:

    foo_base_io_service(const std::string& name)
      : d_who_am_i(name)
    {
        std::cout << "constructing copy " << ++foo_base_io_service::num_instances << "my name is " << d_who_am_i << std::endl;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& get_ref()
    {
        std::cout << "class requested copy of " << d_who_am_i << std::endl;
        return d_ios;
    }

    ~foo_base_io_service()
    {
        std::cout << "Someone 86'd the base_io_service..." << std::endl;
    }

private:

    // this class is not copyable
    foo_base_io_service(const foo_base_io_service&);
    foo_base_io_service& operator=(const foo_base_io_service&);

    std::string d_who_am_i;
    static int num_instances;

    boost::asio::io_service d_ios;
};

extern foo_base_io_service global_timer_io_service;

} // namespace foo

#endif
```

// File global_io_service.cpp

```
#include "global_io_service.h"

namespace foo{
    boost::asio::io_service test_io_service;

    foo_base_io_service global_timer_io_service("FOO_TIMER_SERVICE");

    // static initialization
    int foo_base_io_service::num_instances = 0;
}
```

// FILE main.cpp

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include "global_io_service.h"
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // also causes crash
    boost::asio::deadline_timer crash_timer2(foo::test_io_service);    

    // causes crash
    boost::asio::deadline_timer crash_timer(foo::global_timer_io_service.get_ref());


    return 0 ;
}
```

Here is the backtrace of the crash:

> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_mutex::lock() Line 51
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock::scoped_lock(boost::asio::detail::win_mutex & m) Line 47
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_add_timer_queue(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue_base & queue) Line 477
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::add_timer_queue >(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue > & queue) Line 79
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service >::deadline_timer_service >(boost::asio::io_service & io_service) Line 69
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::deadline_timer_service >::deadline_timer_service >(boost::asio::io_service & io_service) Line 78
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create > >(boost::asio::io_service & owner) Line 81
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(const boost::asio::io_service::service::key & key, boost::asio::io_service::service * (boost::asio::io_service &) * factory) Line 123
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service > >() Line 49
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::use_service > >(boost::asio::io_service & ios) Line 34
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::basic_io_object >,0>::basic_io_object >,0>(boost::asio::io_service & io_service) Line 91
>
> test_io_service.exe!boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer,boost::asio::deadline_timer_service > >::basic_deadline_timer,boost::asio::deadline_timer_service > >(boost::asio::io_service & io_service) Line 151
>
> test_io_service.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 16 C++

Here's what I've learned:

- The issue does not occur in Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.10 or Red Hat 6.5 with boost 1.54.
- The issue appears related to the order of inclusion of Winsock2. For instance, exchanging the order of inclusion with global_io_service.h eliminates the crash.
- The issue appears related to the extern linkage of global_timer_io_service.  Moving the definition of global_timer_io_service into main.cpp eliminates the crash.
- I've found reports of similar crashes occuring on io_service internal critical sections.  Those issues were mostly related to lifetime of io_service objects being passed into timer/socket constructors.  In my case, I think the io_service I'm using was already constructed before main is entered.
- My gut says there is a race condition (perhaps some global state setup in WinSock2?) that prevents proper construction of the io_service object.

Hopefully, I'm having a bad day and invoking undefined behavior.
Otherwise, I'd like to understand why this is happening?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: My gut says that it's [Static Initialization Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) sooner than a (thread) data race.

Comment: @sehe Agreed.  The fiasco makes sense as a possible cause.  Changing the linkage of foo_base_io_service and swapping header inclusion order could both trigger changes in static initialization ordering.

Comment: @lukecfg , any solution so far???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that ASIO selects its io_service implementation on Windows by whether or not `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP` gets defined by `boost/asio/detail/config.hpp`. If defined, it will use the `win_iocp_io_service`. If not, it will use the `task_io_service` - see `boost/asio/io_service.hpp`. If this selection is different across translation units, you will end up initializing the io_service as one and using it as another. They differ in subtle ways, e.g. what mutexes are initialized, so this problem can manifest as a crash due to using an uninitialized mutex.

As for what selects `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP`, let's look at `config.hpp`:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP)
# if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  if defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400)
#   if !defined(UNDER_CE)
#    if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP)
#     define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP 1
#    endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP)
#   endif // !defined(UNDER_CE)
#  endif // defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400)
# endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP)
```

In this case, the controversial macro is `_WIN32_WINNT`, which appears to be getting defined by `WinSock2.h` in your project. Because it's defined in `main.cpp`, but not defined in `global_io_service.cpp`, **you're initializing io_service to use `task_io_service` and calling it as if it used `win_iocp_io_service`**

To resolve the problem, either appropriately define `_WIN32_WINNT` in your compiler definitions or global header file, or just turn the IOCP reactor off altogether by defining `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` (again, globally).

Comment: Awesome answer, I'd upvote if I could, but don't have enough rep.  Appreciate the detail; another reason to hate macros!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lifetime of yoor ioservice. You grab it out of the object.

The ioservice must live longer than all services.

In this example
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html
The ioservice lives longer than the deadline timer.

Edit: Here is a german online book from boris schäling
http://dieboostcppbibliotheken.de/boost.asio-ioservices-und-objekte

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, unless I'm missing something, I don't think the issue is related to the lifetime of the io_service in this particular case.  I added the wrapper 'foo_base_io_service' as mechanism to track the lifetime of the io_service.  I've edited the code above to add a print statement in the destructor.  The destructor never gets called, indicating the object is still alive at time of crash.  I've also added an extern io_service variable 'test_io_service' to bypass the wrapper class.  The test_io_service object produces the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I defined `deadline_timer` before `io_service` in the class header caused this problem.