# Including Boost ASIO conflicts with Amazon Gamelift SDK

Tags: c++, boost, amazon-gamelift

If I include boost ASIO in a header file without any actual use of boost::asio, at any point I call `Aws::GameLift::Server::InitSDK()`, the application will crash from a different thread. How is something like this possible?

`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC4ADEA6AB (ntdll.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000100000023.`

```
ntdll.dll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlEnterCriticalSection() Unknown
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_add_timer_queue(class boost::asio::detail::timer_queue_base &)   C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::waitable_timer_service<struct std::chrono::steady_clock,struct boost::asio::wait_traits<struct std::chrono::steady_clock> >::waitable_timer_service<struct std::chrono::steady_clock,struct boost::asio::wait_traits<struct std::chrono::steady_clock> >(class boost::asio::io_service &)    C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<class boost::asio::waitable_timer_service<struct std::chrono::steady_clock,struct boost::asio::wait_traits<struct std::chrono::steady_clock> > >(class boost::asio::io_service &)   C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(const boost::asio::io_service::service::key & key, boost::asio::io_service::service *(*)(boost::asio::io_service &) factory) Line 124   C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one(bool block, boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 397 C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 159    C++
```

Here is my include - just having this at the top of any header file will trigger the exception after the InitSDK call.

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE
#define CreateEvent CreateEventA
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#undef CreateEvent
```

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2015 Toolset v140
- Boost 1.52.0
- Windows 8.1 SDK (running Windows 10)

I've taken a look at this question: [boost::asio::io_service crash in win_mutex lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520493/boostasioio-service-crash-in-win-mutex-lock)

When I add `#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP`, the exception changes and the callstack is on the main thread. This leads me to believe it has to do with different implementations of the socket service depending on which defines are used.

```
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::construct(struct boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type &)    C++
MyApp.exe!boost::asio::basic_io_object<class boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp>,1>::basic_io_object<class boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp>,1>(class boost::asio::io_service &)    C++
MyApp.exe!std::make_shared<class boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,class boost::reference_wrapper<class boost::asio::io_service> const >(class boost::reference_wrapper<class boost::asio::io_service> const &&)   C++
MyApp.exe!websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint<struct websocketpp::config::asio_client::transport_config>::init_asio(class boost::asio::io_service *,class std::error_code &) C++
MyApp.exe!websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint<struct websocketpp::config::asio_client::transport_config>::init_asio(class boost::asio::io_service *) C++
MyApp.exe!sio::client_impl::client_impl(void)   C++
MyApp.exe!sio::client::client(void) C++
MyApp.exe!Aws::GameLift::Internal::GameLiftServerState::InitializeNetworking(void)  Unknown
MyApp.exe!Aws::GameLift::Server::InitSDK(void)  Unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the version of Gamelift SDK I have is using Boost 1.61 and this conflicts with the Boost 1.52 that I'm using in my main project.

I upgraded my use of Boost to 1.61 to match theirs and suddenly - no more exception coming from Gamelift. Surprise.